# Ethereum install debian

Tags: debian, ethereum

Is there any update about installing etherium on debian linux?
This is what is currently given, but it is for ubuntu:

https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/installing_linux.html

Answer (score 0):

No - there is no update. Debian is still not officially supported.

But it *is* possible to install it using the Ubuntu PPA (I've done it with Jessie), but if you want a step-by-step guide you'll have to provide more information. i.e. **which** Debian release you are running

`cat /etc/Debian_version` or `lsb_release -sr`

Note: why are you asking on Stackoverflow about what is written on another site?? Or have you just phrased your question badly?